apt command not installing latest version of apts
So i've been using ubuntu as my main os and I'm still trying to learn my way through it - and linux in general.
But I've noticed that (sudo) apt install is not installing the latest versions of apts in a few instances.
For example, Nodejs is currently in version 21.x, but installing it with apt command, I get the 12.x . While I at least need 14.x, I'm unable to either update it or just straight up download any version above 12.x
I'm currently on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
I already tried running
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

As I'm new to linux I'm still kinda lost on what to do. Any help would be appreciated.
